# In angular 5 Type of array of objects returns object. How to fix this

Tags: javascript, angular

This is the function i am using in my code.Here inside the getOriginData(this.encodedData) httpclient is used and i have called the respective API to get the response.

```
  //Ts
  getOriginDetails() {
  this.createCaseService.getOriginData(this.encodedData)
  .subscribe((response) => {
    this.originData = response;
    console.log(typeof this.originData ); // ans is object

  },
    respError => {
      console.log('Error in api');
    });
}

// HTML
 <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Origin</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <select  (change)=" selectOrigin($event)" class="custom-select customArrow">
        <option value="">-- Select Origin Data --</option>
        <option *ngFor="let item of originData; let i = index;" [value]="item.id">{{item.name}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
```

so here is the response from API as shown below in the picture, which is clearly seen as an array of objects.[image]
.But when i am checking the type of this response its showing object.And when i am using it in html using ngFor its showing the following error.
[image]
So my concern is is there any way to change its type? Why is it not returning not array when I am checking type? Is there any other way to get rid of this problem.Coz i need to use this response for iteration using *ngFor.

Comment: Can we have also the line where you initialize originData please. Thanks

Comment: originData: any;

Before i was using   originData: any = [ ];. Neither is working

Comment: Use: `Object.keys(obj).forEach((i[key]) => {});`

Comment: typeof array will surely be an object, check Array.isArray(response)

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: It returned true. Then why the above error is resulting.(as shown in the image)

Comment: This is not below to type. It is problem in NgFor by yourself

Answer (score 0):

It is becausse array have type object. See example 
Because array is reference.

```js
   const arr = [1,2,3];
    console.log(typeof(arr));
```

**Can you show your HTML when you use *ngFor ??**

Comment: I got it. Thanks . But my problem is why that error is there. It preventing me from iteration through the array. Refer the image shown in the question

Comment: Give me your html where you use *NgFor

Comment: I have added in the question. Follow it

Comment: You must use this http call in onInit method.

Comment: You define method to get data.But you dont call it.To use is in html it must get before view render. So call it in onInit method

Comment: Actually this is inside a dialog content, i.e i have created a second component inside the same ts file. So i have called this function inside the constructor.

Comment: You must called it where you have this select with options or pass data to Dialog

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189945/discussion-between-anton-skybun-and-abhiz).

Answer (score 0):

You can try do conversion of your data in service

```
getOriginData(data: Array<String>): Observable<Inter[]> {
return this.http.get<Inter[]>(Url, {params: this.params});
}
```

Where Inter is interface of your data:

```
export interface Dir {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    value: string;
    defaultValue: string;
    isActive?: boolean;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue can appear, when this.originData is before declared as an object.
For example:

```
originData = {};
response = [1, 2, 3];

this.originData = this.response;
```

Will result in originData still being an object. Fix this by doing

```
originData = [];
```

Comment: i have declared like this. originData: any; And if i ll declare it originData = []; then it is showing error in my subscribe methode, in the line " this.originData = response; "

Comment: then try originData: any[]